# UISplitViewController & UITableView slide to delete obscured by SectionIndex

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, indexing, uisplitviewcontroller

iOS 7 SDK

When sliding right to left over a UITableViewCell to enable 'Delete' mode, the red 'Delete' UIView appears to be partially obscured by the SectionIndex.

i.e.

[image]

Is there a fix?

EDIT: Even if the SectionIndex background is transparent or white, the 'Delete' is still partially hidden and obscured.

EDIT 2: It's been suggested in Twitter that I create a custom UITableViewCell and make it narrower and move the default 'delete' button, but I don't want (nor think I should have to) go to that effort for something that should have already been provided for by Apple and the default SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I needed to finish the project i resorted to writing a custom UITableViewCell.

Here's the proof:

[image]

And the 'fix' was in the new subclass of UITableViewCell, to change the default class method:

```
- ( void ) setFrame:( CGRect )frame
{
    frame.size.width -= 30.0f;

    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Hope that helps someone else, at least until Apple Fix it.